# Visual Studio Code: launch.json starts JavaScript file instead of TypeScript file even though ts file has been specified as program parameter

Tags: debugging, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have the following directories:

```
.vscode
-- launch.json
-- tasks.json
build
-- script
-- -- main.js
-- -- main.js.map
node_modules
src
-- script
-- -- main.ts
-- typings
-- tsd.json
gulpfile.js
```

And of course other things like readmes and the content of node_modules etc.

Anyway, my launch.json looks as following:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "debug",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/script/main.ts",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--nolazy"
        ],
        "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        },
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/build/script/",
        "sourceMaps": true
    },
    {
        "name": "attach",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 5858
    }
]}
```

and my gulpfile for building the typescript as follows:

```
gulp.task('typescript', function() {
gulp.src('./src/script/**/*.ts')
    .pipe(ts({
        noImplicitAny: true,
        target: 'ES6',
        module: 'commonjs',
        removeComments: true
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())     
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/script/'));
});
```

Now back to my problem:

As said in the title, VS Code starts the debugger and it actually works but it debugs the main.js file instead of the main.ts file.

As far as I understand I have to set main.ts as the *program* parameter and the directory containing the js files as the *outDir* parameter.

At the moment I am somewhat stuck as I feel like my configuration is correct but for some reason, well obviously, it isn't.

Maybe someone can see the mistake I have made :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. First, try to execute the js file from your launch.json.

Then, you also need a tsconfig.json file in the root of the project, even if you compile with gulp. This file has a "sourceMap" parameter that needs to be set to true in order to be able to debug ts files with source maps.

A sample tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I tried this, didn't really change anything.

As far as I know tsconfig.json is just the config file for the typescript compiler (tsc). When using the gulp integration and setting such parameters using the parameters there I don't think it is needed. The sourceMap property specifies that sourcemaps should be generated.

I use the  npm package "gulp-sourcemaps" to create the sourcemaps.